# How to get MSTeam channels of a particular user have access by passing User ID or User Principal Name

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-devops-rest-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have tried to specific user joined teams by using query it worked
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{User](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BUser) ID or User Principal Name}/joinedteams

now how to get channels from the particular team which the user has access by passing User ID or User Principal Name
i tried below queries but no luck

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{User](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BUser) ID or User Principal Name}/teams/{Team id}/joinedchannels

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{User](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BUser) ID or User Principal Name}/teams/{Team id}/channels

Comment: Please have look at this doc:-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/get-teamchanneluser?view=teams-ps

Comment: Using Graph API it is not possible for particular user. You can get MSTeam channels of a particular user using above powershell command.
[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI9Q1.png

Comment: HI @Sayali-MSFT basically we are not going to use powershell cmd's, any alternative way?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any alternative for this.